# Грязные деньги

Tags: пунктуация

"Грязные" деньги - нужны кавычки или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужны. Выражение давно вошло в язык, своего рода идиомой.
Впрочем, не соглаcен и с тем, что и значение составляющих здесь какое-то особое или необычное. 
У Кузнецова (статья "грязный") кавычек нет ни в одном из двух значений ("нечестно нажитые" и "до вычета налога").

Comment: Согласна, что это практически идиома. Тем не менее, встречаются варианты написания и закавыченные и без кавычек. Например, книга Клаус Коттке ""Грязные" деньги - как с ними бороться?". Из аннотации: "Справочник по налоговому законодательству в области "грязных" денег. "Грязные" деньги, появляющиеся в результате уклонения от налогов и криминальной деятельности, будут существовать всегда, но всегда с ними будет вестись борьба. (Издательство "Дело и сервис", 2005. Перевод 9-го переработанного немецкого издания.
 Науч.редактор к.э.н. К.К. Баранова.)

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужны. Кавычками выделяются слова, употребленные в переносном или особом, необычном значении (см. Розенталь Д.Э и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ. М.: ЧеРо, 1999. §128. Слова, употребляемые в необычном, условном, ироническом значении). "Грязные" деньги - деньги, добытые незаконными, аморальными и т.п. способами. 
Значение 'основанный на использовании предосудительных приемов, средств и т.п., вызывающий моральное отвращение' для слова *грязный* не является  основным, даже в словаре помечается как переносное (например, см.: Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка Т.Ф.Ефремовой).